# Oracle - Second level subquery cannot see field from main query

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle 12c the following query works, but not in Oracle 11g, because second level subquery cannot see field from main query.
How can I rewrite the query to work in Oracle 11 too?

```
SELECT   lvl, 
         unique_code, 
         (
            SELECT   unique_code
            FROM     (
                        SELECT   p.unique_code
                        FROM     tree p
                        WHERE    p.lvl = t.lvl - 1
                             AND p.unique_code < t.unique_code
                        ORDER BY p.unique_code DESC
                     )
            WHERE    ROWNUM = 1
         ) AS parent_unique_code
FROM     tree t
```

Tree contains rows as follows:
*(Please don't rely on the format/structure of the unique code, it is much complex in reality.)*

```
lvl         unique_code
-----------------------
1           A
2           A/X
2           A/Y
3           A/Y/T
2           A/Z
1           B
2           B/X
```

The expected result is the following:

```
lvl         unique_code   parent_unique_code
--------------------------------------------
1           A                      
2           A/X           A
2           A/Y           A
3           A/Y/T         A/Y
2           A/Z           A
1           B             
2           B/X           B
```

Thank you

Comment: Do a LEFT JOIN instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you only need a `max` in your nested query:

```
SELECT   lvl, 
         unique_code, 
         (
            SELECT   max(p.unique_code)
                        FROM     tree p
                        WHERE    p.lvl = t.lvl - 1
                             AND p.unique_code < t.unique_code
         ) AS parent_unique_code FROM     tree t
```

Comment: Oh, such an easy solution. I dug myself into this and other related problems that I could not see the forest from the tree :)  Thanks