# Oracle 11g: Need to get the longest matching string that starts with another string

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables with data:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1 (
  ID NUMBER,
  LABEL VARCHAR2(50)
);
CREATE TABLE tbl2 (
  ID NUMBER,
  SRC VARCHAR2(400)
);

INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES (1, 'foobar');
INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES (2, 'foo');
INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES (3, 'bar');

INSERT INTO tbl2 (SRC) VALUES ('foo: yeah');
INSERT INTO tbl2 (SRC) VALUES ('foobar: nope');
```

I am trying to update the ID field of tbl2 by match the longest matching string from tbl1. My intention is that the 'foo: yeah' entry should get ID 2, and the 'foobar: nope' entry should get an ID of 1:

```
UPDATE tbl2 t2
SET t2.ID = (SELECT t1.ID
             FROM tbl1 t1
             WHERE t2.SRC LIKE t1.LABEL || '%');
```

Doing this results in an error: "single-row subquery returns more than one row". That makes sense to me, so I tried this:

```
UPDATE tbl2 t2
SET t2.ID = (SELECT t1.ID
             FROM tbl1 t1
             WHERE t2.SRC LIKE t1.LABEL || '%'
             AND ROWNUM=1
             ORDER BY LENGTH(t1.LABEL) DESC);
```

But now I get this error: "missing right parenthesis".
I don't understand this error in this context, the parenthesis are well formed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "missing right parenthesis" is because of the `order by` clause in the subquery; it isn't valid there.

You're also getting the `ROWNUM` in the same level that you're ordering. That won't do quite what you expect. The ordering happens last, so you'll actually get one row - any row, which one is indeterminate - and then you'll order that single row by length, which doesn't do anything.

You need another level of subquery to get the row you're interested in:

```
UPDATE tbl2 t2
SET t2.ID = (
  SELECT ID FROM (
    SELECT t1.ID
    FROM tbl1 t1
    WHERE t2.SRC LIKE t1.LABEL || '%'
    ORDER BY LENGTH(t1.LABEL) DESC
  )
  WHERE ROWNUM=1
);
```

... but that unfortunately also doesn't work, and will get another error: `ORA-00904: "T2"."SRC": invalid identifier`.

That's because you can't refer to a table or alias two levels of subquery down, at least until 12c (possibly; there was a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36565737/266304) that seemed to suggest it works now, and also [this slightly older one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34995770/266304)).

You can use [the `FIRST` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions065.htm) and `KEEP DENSE_RANK` to achieve this:

```
UPDATE tbl2 t2
SET t2.ID = (
  SELECT MIN(t1.ID) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY LENGTH(t1.LABEL) DESC)
  FROM tbl1 t1
  WHERE t2.SRC LIKE t1.LABEL || '%'
);

2 rows updated.

select * from tbl2;

        ID SRC                
---------- --------------------
         2 foo: yeah           
         1 foobar: nope
```

You could also use `KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY LENGTH(t1.LABEL))`, i.e. `LAST` instead of `FIRST`, and without the `DESC`, which is logically the same if you don't have nulls.

Comment: That works great, and gets me to use a few things I've never used before (KEEP, DENSE_RANK & FIRST). Thanks!

Comment: The use of MIN(t1.ID) (or MAX(t1.ID)) seems to only be there because the results must be aggregated, right? There should only be one value of ID, and it's not really selecting the smaller (or largest) ID value, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
update tbl2 set tbl2.id =
 (
    with a as (select src, label, 
                      row_number() over (partition by src order by length(label) desc) rn 
               from tbl2 join tbl1 on src like label || '%')
    select id from tbl1 join a using (label) where tbl2.src = a.src and rn = 1
 )
```

Comment: This works well too, but I gave the answer to Alex Poole, because he gave a much more detailed explanation. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, no worries - happy to help. I couldn't care less if SO did away with these "reputation points" altogether - they just encourage rushed, not very well thought out answers. Even more so on the Mathematics side. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MAX( ... ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK [FIRST|LAST] ORDER BY ... )` to get the maximum value where for those values which are first (or last) in the `ORDER BY`.

```
UPDATE tbl2 t2
SET t2.id = ( SELECT MAX( id ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST
                                      ORDER BY LENGTH( LABEL ) )
              FROM tbl1
              WHERE t2.src LIKE label || '%' );
```

**Result**:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl2;

        ID SRC 
---------- -------------
         2 foo: yeah
         1 foobar: nope
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the same as Alex's answer. Alex answered first, and gets the credit.